# Email "FROM address" is changed to an unexpected email address

Tags: email, domain, dmarc

I have enabled DMARC settings in my domain (drkotzi.org). Now when I send emails from my email address (sales@drkotzi.org) to email lists or email groups, I can see that the email's ***from address*** and ***to address*** become identical. can someone please tell me why this is happening? because of this sometimes my emails are now being sent into spam directory also.
[image]

but when I remove DMARC settings from drkotzi.org, everything goes back to normal and I can send emails to email groups without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: **This is probably a feature of the mailing list to prevent DMARC from failing.**

It is well known that DMARC does not survive DMARC+SPF on mailing lists, as to prevent SPF tests from failing the list server must change the *envelope sender* to one from their own domain.

DMARC+DKIM might survive, if the message is both DKIM signed and the mailing list does not alter the message body. For e.g. legal reasons a mailing list might want to change the message body to contain some disclaimers or unsubscribe information. In order to get this kind of messages delivered one might create an implementation where also the `From` header gets rewritten. Also, not nearly everyone DKIM sign their messages, so this is quite a suitable workaround, although it is not following any standards.

Comment: Thanks for your information. However, I saw in several places that we can do certain workarounds to get this task done. 

https://dmarc.org/wiki/FAQ#I_operate_a_mailing_list_and_I_want_to_interoperate_with_DMARC.2C_what_should_I_do.3F

can do these things with Gsuite?

Comment: @yello_flash: What you see exactly matches option #3.B in your link, i.e. replace the original `From` header and add the original sender as `Reply-To`. And the options #1 and #2 have more serious problems for practical use, which are also described in the link. So it is actually already the best way chosen.